# Paypal buttons without form tags

Tags: forms

The html for a donation button  provided by Paypal forces excessive white space on the page. Is it possible to link back to Paypal without the form tag? I have the Paypal button graphic which I can anchor to html code if it is not a form element.

Comment: Please post the HTML that PayPal has generated for you.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do it without a form; I did so a while ago. I don't remember specifically how I did it, but I can give you this example, and if you post your HTML I could help you turn it into a link instead:
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=ben%40happyspork%2ecom&item_name=Sporktris%20Support&item_number=1&no_shipping=0&no_note=1&tax=0&currency_code=CAD&lc=CA&bn=PP%2dDonationsBF&charset=UTF%2d8

You might even be able to just modify that link to use your data instead of mine.